# Why was this question closed ?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

This is getting plain ridiculous:

https://superuser.com/questions/204710/what-happened-to-the-corel-forums-for-paintshop-pro-closed

If this isn't a question about computer software (support for it) then I give up! I even took the time out to answer another PSP related question and I even thought about creating a wiki for it as suggested.

But not now if this is the kind of knee jerk INSTANT (it was closed almost as fast as I raised it) and really makes SuperUser a real turn off.

Comment: You asked whether a website was up or down, that's not a topic for SU.

Answer (score 17):

> If this isn't a question about computer software (support for it) then I give up!

No, it wasn't about software/computer support.

I suggest you read the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq):

```
[SuperUser is about ... ] and it is not about ...

* websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
```

The question was clearly about a website, there for off-topic, there for closed.